# How to display a video when a wrong password is entered

Tags: gui, pam, mplayer, startx, display-server

I want to display a video when a wrong password is entered (say only in GUI login screen or within the display manager).

I have added a line to `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` to run my script `/usr/local/bin/movie`

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [default=ignore]                pam_exec.so seteuid /usr/local/bin/movie
```

The script `/usr/local/bin/movie` is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mplayer /usr/local/movie.mp4
exit0
```

When entering password, I only get 0.1 s of black screen instead of the film.

**How can I make my script working?**

Comment: As in "Uh uh uh, you didn't say the magic word"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display within a gnome session, add `DISPLAY=<display ID>`. For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/mplayer -fr /usr/local/movie.mp4
exit 0
```

with `-fs` for full screen.